# How to handle Push on App not running state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, ios10

Is it possible to open the iOS App based on push notification content? I believe it's not possible. Is there any other way around? I believe we can go with the widget in iOS10, right? Please suggest some good solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever your payload has `content-available:1` your app will get called in the backgroundstate as soon as it arrives and will call [`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application). It will only not get called if the user killed the app manually. (This doesn't launch your app. It requires your app to be launched though)

Having that said if your app was terminated (by user) but the user taps on the notitication then your app is **launched** from didFinishLaunching...delegate method.

Comment: Yes , thanks! So its not possible to launch the app on push receive without user action, right?

Comment: @user1591698 can you define exactly what you mean by launch? Do you mean to just open and bring and magically bring it to foreground? Or you mean just have it launched in the background and perform some tasks?

Comment: Sorry, I need to do your first point (just open and bring and magically bring it to foreground)

Comment: It almost never happens. Imagine if it did, then you would be in tha middle of browsing and then suddenly your bank app opened. Though if your app has VOIP then it would make sense for fhe all to just pop on your screen when someone is calling you.

Comment: Yes Agree, Alternatively, we can go with App extension - show our customized view in today notification section while the app is in background state (suspended state -we can utilize remote notification to make our app change from suspended state to background state). I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the user **taps** on push notification the application launches from not running state to running state the in  AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

}
in this function you can check application is launch from push or application icon 

var notification: [AnyHashable: Any]? = (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [AnyHashable: Any])
if notification != nil {
    print("app received notification from remote\(notification)")
    application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notification)
}
else {
    print("app did not receive notification")
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! Is it possible to open app without user taps on app not running state?

Comment: User can open application from the application icon on that case you need a backend guy that track all the notification and send you status of last unread push notification

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can not open ios applications on push notifications but we can wake up the app on push notifications. Its called  VOIP notification.  You can have more info regarding this from below link https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: Ok Thanks! Will check.