# Playing an audio clip even when the app is not running

Tags: ios, push-notification, voip

In my app, I used VoIP notification to play a long alarm on app **not running state** as per suggestion [Silent Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871116/how-to-handle-push-on-app-not-running-state), But app got rejected in the following points

> Your app is not in compliance with Guideline 4.2.1 using the VoIP API in a manner that it is not intended.
>
> 2.5.4 Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc. If your app uses location background mode, include a reminder that doing so may dramatically decrease battery life.

Is there any way to rectify these issues or would be good if we get any alternative to play a long alarm on push receive in app **not running state**?

I beleive, `UNNotificationContentExtension` would help to show our custom notification on push receives but how to play automatic audio on push receive,

Can we handle in push message `sound` key?

or

Can we do this by default `UNNotificationContentExtension` methods in

```
mediaPlay() mediaPlayPauseButtonFrame()
```

But there is no way to play automatic audio here. please correct me if am wrong.

My requirement will be, I need to play a long audio in any app state and audio should stop on user click of stop button or notification(it usually launch our app).

Comment: If your app is well configured with voip push notification, then you can play max 30 seconds of audio file with scheduling local notification. Check more over here https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: Yes, we did the same. But app was rejected with a notes "Your app is not in compliance with Guideline 4.2.1 using the VoIP API in a manner that it is not intended."

Answer (score 2):

You can't use background location/ VOIP for other purposes, so if you are using them just to keep your app active in the background, Apple will reject it.

Use them in your app only when it is directly relevant to the features and services provided by the app. Location-based APIs/VOIP shouldn’t be used to provide emergency services or alarm systems, etc. Ensure that you notify and obtain consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data. If your app uses background services, be sure to explain the purpose in your app. Refer to the Human Interface Guidelines for best practices on doing so.

You can use `sound` key in your push but audio can only be played for maximum 30 seconds. There's no way like audio should stop when user taps on notification.

Comment: Ok Thanks! So there is no way to play long audio, any idea about UNNotificationContentExtension?

Comment: Sorry buddy but I haven't tried my hands on UNNotificationContentExtension

Comment: Ok Thanks! Will try

Comment: Cool. Good luck! It would be great if you can up-vote this answer .

Comment: Sure.. Thanks for the reply

Comment: No problem @Gopik. Welcome anytime.